# Conceptual question about rotating cube about unstable equilibrium point

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics

Let's say we have a **cube** of mass $m$ and side **2a** is held poised on one of its edges on a horizontal
surface. It is released from this position and allowed to tip.

Here we have two cases :

**Case 1** : the surface is sufficiently rough to stop the edge from moving. 
**Case 2** : the edge of the cube can slide freely on the table.

I have a couple of questions about this question and how to go about this - any guidance would be much appreciated.

Generally, I want to go about this question using energy - since any other method requires too many variables to manage. For **CASE 1**, where the edge is not moving, am I right in thinking that the
$\Delta GPE$ of the COM moving down by a distance of $(\sqrt{2}-1a)$ = $\frac{1}{2}I_{edge}\omega^2$? where $I_{edge}$ is the MoI of the cube rotating about the edge? \

Then, for **CASE 2** : here we do something similar. Since there is effectively no friction, the COM will just move vertically downwards. Therefore $\Delta GPE$ = $T_{rot}$ + $T_{linear}$ right? Where $T_{rot}$ = the rotational K.E. of the cube rotating about the COM, and the linear K.E. coming from the fact that the COM is falling vertically downwards.

Please let me know if my reasoning is correct - and if not, any pointers would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that your understanding might not be correct? Questions which ask "Am I right?" can often be answered Yes or No. Such answers are not useful for others, so they are not good for this site. If you explain why you doubt that your guess is correct then we can provide an answer which might be useful for others.

Comment: You describe this as a "conceptual question" yet you have not identified what concept you are having difficulty with. You are clearly asking how to solve a problem, but you have not explained what the problem about the toppling cube is asking you to find.